# error in the mongodb query to retrieve from array

Tags: java, mongodb-query

I have a database named 'test' and collection 'testCollection'
and my database looks like this

```
{
  "_id" : "12345",
  "info" : {
    "fname" : "rahul",
    "lname" : "raj",
    "city" : "bangalore"
  }
}
```

after connecting to localhost through MongoClient I did the following

```
DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("testCollection");
```

referring to one of the posts in this site I came up with this query
but i'm getting error in the following line.

```
DBCursor cursor = coll.find({info: {$elemMatch: { fname: "rahul" }}});
```

plese help me. where i'm going wrong.i'm new to mongodb

Comment: You don't have an array here. Array is []. Here you simply need to have `info.fname:"rahul"`

Comment: thanks for the info. but still its giving syntax error. my code is DBCursor cursor = coll.find({info.fname:"rahul"});

Comment: Which programming language is it and what exactly is the error: error returned from MongoDB or not? You probably need to put names of the fields in quotes, that's an obvious one :)

Comment: hey thanx, I'm using Java .. its working now. after trying many combinations finally i got wat i was looking for              BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("name.fname","rahul");      DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);